# Same endpoint for differente controllers in NestJS

Tags: nestjs

Hope someone can help me with this. I'm new with NestJs

I need to use the same path for different controllers based on information received in the header request.

Right now I'm ussing this code in my app.controller.ts to intercept and redirect, but I can only use it for Get requests, not for Post, Put, Delete, etc.

```
export class AppController {
  @Get(':endpoint')
  @Post(':endpoint')
  @Patch(':endpoint')
  @Put(':endpoint')
  @Delete(':endpoint')
  redirect(@Param() param, @Headers('authorization') bearerToken, @Res() res) {
    const entity = getEntityFromToken(bearerToken);

    return res.redirect(`/${entity}s/${param.endpoint}`);
  }
}
```

There is anyway I can do this? The idea being when someone makes a request, I extract information from my token and call the apropiate controller. Should I use Dynamic Modules? I'm not shure how.

Thank you!!

I've tried using res.redirect but only works for Get methods I think.
The idea being when someone makes a request, I extract information from my token and call the apropiate controller based on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use same endpoint / path for different HTTP methods, you can add multiple methods with same endpoint (url) and appropriate HTTP method decorator. e.g.,

```js
export class AppController {
  @Get(':endpoint')
  getEndpoint(@Param() param, @Headers('authorization') bearerToken, @Res() res) {
    // GET specific code
  }

  @Post(':endpoint')
  postEndpoint(@Param() param, @Headers('authorization') bearerToken, @Res() res) {
    // POST specific code
  }

  @Patch(':endpoint')
  patchEndpoint(@Param() param, @Headers('authorization') bearerToken, @Res() res) {
    // PATCH specific code
  }

  @Put(':endpoint')
  putEndpoint(@Param() param, @Headers('authorization') bearerToken, @Res() res) {
    // PUT specific code
  }


  @Delete(':endpoint')
  deleteEndpoint(@Param() param, @Headers('authorization') bearerToken, @Res() res){
    // DELETE specific code
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand. My question was about sending the request to different controllers based on the information received on the header. For example, I have Controller 1 and Controller 2 with different responses. Both use the same POST endpoint. But I want to redirect the request based on the header in the HTTP request. How could I do this?